# How could Dean Thomas produce a woolen hat?

Tags: harry-potter

> Dean produced a woolen hat, which Harry placed carefully upon Dobby’s head, muffling his batlike ears.

Seriously? How could he do something like that? Hermione had to knit them!! 
If wizards could produce clothes why did Lupin have old clothes? Why did they have shops for clothes? And also Ron didn't try and conjure shoes, he gave him his own.

> Ron sat on the edge of the grave and stripped off his shoes and socks, which he placed upon the elf’s bare feet.

(I also remember firecrackers at Hogwarts could produce hats but this could be explained simply because the cracker already had the materials inside it, and crafted the gift it produced randomly each time. It could also, for example,  increase magically the quantities of some materials.)

Rowling must get some facts together and stop contradicting herself. If anyone has a logical explanation please share it but I think it's a plot-hole.

Comment: He produced it *from a pocket*. i.e. he already had it in his pocket beforehand.

Comment: You have a quote for that?

Comment: @ApostolisKennedy: Are you happy with a dictionary definition? https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/produce Check number 3 (of the verb)

Comment: yeah I thought you said it because you remembered something.. I guess it's possible

Comment: I'm upvoting this purely because it made me giggle.

Comment: As a non-native english speaker I'm upvoting in solidarity, I had the same question when I first read that part, and had to look the term up in a dictionary.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The hat was already in his pocket. He didn't create it by magic -- **he didn't even have a wand with him**.

> 3 Show or provide (something) for consideration, inspection, or use.
>   ‘he produced a sheet of paper from his pocket’
>
> <sub>[Oxford Dictionary meaning for "produce"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/produce)</sub>

> “I miss my wand,” Hermione said miserably. “I wish Mr. Ollivander could have made me another one too.”
>
> Mr. Ollivander had sent Luna a new wand that morning. She was out on the back lawn at that moment, testing its capabilities in the late afternoon sun. **Dean, who had lost his wand to the Snatchers, was watching rather gloomily**.
>
> <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, Chapter 26, Gringotts</sup></sub>

Comment: well it doesn't say from his pocket thats why I thought he produced it magically. That's the most probable explanation

Comment: Don't worry about it, I interpreted that the same way you did first time reading the series. Glad I could clear this up for you

Answer (score 0):

## There is no way to magic clothing out of thin air

[Conjuration](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Conjuration) is an advanced branch of Transfiguration, and isn't taught to students unless they take Transfiguration at N.E.W.T level. In addition, there is no known charm that can conure something like an article of clothing, though Bill and Charlie Weasley (Both of whom had long since graduated from Hogwarts and were skilled Wizards) did once conjure table cloths, so it is possible to conjure materials that can make clothing. I imagine with a bit of concentration, one could conjure a table cloth around themselves as a Toga.

So there's no spell Dean could have used to conjure a knitted woollen hat, and even if there were, Dean almost certainly wouldn't have known what it is or how to cast it.

That's not to say that Hermione didn't use magic to help her Knit, however. There exists a *[Knitting Charm](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Knitting_charm)* that causes knitting needles to tirelessly knit whatever you instruct them to, provided you can keep them stocked with wool. Molly Weasley employs this charm often, usually around Christmas time. Hermione uses this same charm to help her knit the hats, as she says

> "I'm a really slow knitter without magic but now I'm back at school I should be able to make lots more."

It's worth noting that she also made hats outside of Hogwarts, because she wanted to, but couldn't use magic to produce them due to her being underage.

And, as others have mentioned, Dean did not actually produce a hat *magically*, he simply happened to have one on his person.

Comment: The magical crackers make hats

Comment: The magical crackers _contain_ hats, just like they can contain food. Food cannot be conjured, because it is one of the principal exceptions of Gamp's Law. More likely, the crackers have been made subject to an Undetectable Extension Charm to house their contents, which have been created beforehand.

Comment: so the mice are just living in the crackers?

Comment: Potentially. I don't have all the facts, I'm not JK. All I know is that food cannot be conjured, and that there is no known spell that can be used to conjure clothing.